# How would I change the component props onClick with a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to change the value of the prop onClick. Basically the model is set up to show only one input bar if the enum is set to one and vise versa for two. How would I switch the value of the prop with an onClick function? Below is what I have tried to this point. Right now I am getting the following error: "Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Enum_Search_Inputs | null | undefined>'"

```
 const [pickInput, setPickInput] = useState(search.inputs)

       <Breadcrumb
      borderBottom={'1px'}
      borderColor={'white'}
      color={'white'}
      separator=""
      
    >
      <BreadcrumbItem>
        <Button color={'white'} variant='link' onClick={() => setPickInput(pickInput === 'two')}>Search by location</Button>
      </BreadcrumbItem>
      <BreadcrumbItem>
      <Button color={'white'} variant='link' onClick={() => setPickInput(pickInput === 'one')} >Search by keyword</Button>
      </BreadcrumbItem>
    </Breadcrumb>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `boolean` type when you declare `pickInput`

```
 const [pickInput, setPickInput] = useState<Enum_Search_Inputs | null | undefined | boolean>(search.inputs)
```

Comment: That did get rid of the error; however, the goal is to change the value of the prop onClick and it didn't do that. Am I maybe setting it up wrong?

Comment: What do you mean `change the value of the prop onClick`?

Comment: The props value (search.inputs) determines how many inputs are displayed in the component. so if search.inputs = 'one' only one input is displayed; whereas, if it is 'two' then two inputs are displayed. So the buttons I am assigning the onClick should switch between one input and two inputs on click

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set the state as a boolean instead of as a one or a two. Your function should look like the one below if you're trying to set the state to be the word "one" or "two", though I'd definitely recommend using an integer for that.

```
() => setPickInput("one")}

() => setPickInput("two")}
```

Right now, you're actually doing a comparison inside the function where you set your state (pickInput === 'one') which is going to return a boolean to your setPickInput function based on whether your variable pickInput's value is 'one' instead of actually setting a value inside it.

[React Docs link to hooks and state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

[JS Comparisons documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Comment: That makes sense. So search.inputs is actually an enum on a model that determines how many inputs are displayed in the component. so I am trying to change the value of the enum from 'one' to 'two' onClick. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. Just for reference though, having an enum with values like "one", "two", "three", etc. is probably bad practice. Try swapping out the enum's keys or consider just making your object a standard JS object.

Comment: Right, most of the time, it is not the route I would take; however, with the technology involved in the project, it actually makes the most sense here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting up a function that used state to set the value on click.

```
      function searchLocationHandler() {
    setPickInput('two')
    search.inputs = 'two'
  }
  function searchKeywordHandler() {
    setPickInput('one')
    search.inputs = 'one'
  }
```